# How to iterate over generic list

Tags: java, loops, java-8, iteration

I have a class in that I take one list of generic type. Now I am trying to iterate over that list to get the value of that class. In `getOrderAmount()` method I trying to iterate.

```
@Document(collection = Cart.FIELDS.COLLECTION)
public class Cart extends BaseOrderEntity {

    public interface FIELDS extends BaseOrderEntity.FIELDS {
        String COLLECTION = "cart";
        String LIST_ORDERS = "orderList";
        String CART_TYPE = "cartType";
    }

    @Field(value = FIELDS.LIST_ORDERS)
    private List<T> orderList;
    @Field(value = FIELDS.CART_TYPE)
    private Integer cartType;

    public List<T> getOrderList() {
        return orderList;
    }

    public void setOrderList(List<T> orderList) {
        this.orderList = orderList;
    }

    public Integer getCartType() {
        return cartType;
    }

    public void setCartType(Integer cartType) {
        this.cartType = cartType;
    }

    @Override
    public RefCollectionType getRefCollectionType() {
        if (T.class.getClass() == FoodItemOrderDetails.class.getClass()) {
            return RefCollectionType.FOOD;
        } else if (T.class.getClass() == LaundryItemOrderDetails.class.getClass()) {
            return RefCollectionType.LAUNDRY;

        } else if (T.class.getClass() == HousekeepingItemOrderDetails.class.getClass()) {
            return RefCollectionType.HOUSEKEEPING;

        }
        return RefCollectionType.FOOD;
    }

    @Override
    public double getOrderAmount() {
        double totalfoodOrderAmount = 0.0;
        for (FoodItemOrderDetails foodItem : orderList) {
            totalfoodOrderAmount = totalfoodOrderAmount + (foodItem.getPrice() * foodItem.getQuantity());
        }
        return totalfoodOrderAmount;
    }
}
```

**The generic classes are here.**

```
FoodItemOrderDetails
LaundryItemOrderDetails
HousekeepingItemOrderDetails
```

Comment: And the problem is? Do you get any error?

Comment: Hows about `for(T item : list) { if(item instanceof FoodItemOrderDetails) //do logic}}`

Comment: The confusing part of this question is... What are those `@Document`, `FIELDS`, `RefCollectionType` all about? Is it linked with your problem?

Comment: This cannot be correct and will not compile. Where is the generic parameter definition of T. You are missing sth. like `class Cart<T> extends ...`. Otherwise the List must be "typed" with List<?>.

Comment: Where is `T` defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have an interface like `OrderDetails` which should have 2 methods `getQuantity()` and `getPrice()`. Now implement that interface in `FoodItemOrderDetails`,
`LaundryItemOrderDetails`, `HousekeepingItemOrderDetails`.

```
    for (OrderDetails item : orderList) {
        totalAmount = totalAmount + (item .getPrice() * item.getQuantity());
    }
```

Your Interface should looks like below.

```
interface OrderDetails {
    Double getPrice();

    Integer getQuantity();
}
```

Your classes should look like below.

```
class FoodItemOrderDetails implements OrderDetails {
    @Override
    public Double getPrice() {
        // return the price for FoodItem
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getQuantity() {
        // return the Quantity for FoodItem
        return null;
    }
}
```

You can use Java-8 stream.

```
List<OrderDetails> details = new ArrayList<>();
double total = details.stream().mapToDouble(e -> e.getPrice() * e.getQuantity()).sum();
```